# Is it Possible to Use Multiple DT formatStyle functions in R Shiny?

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I'm wondering if it is possible to use multiple DT::formatStyle functions in R shiny.

I would like to implement colors (green and red for positive and negative numbers, respectively) as well as highlighting the last row to display column sums.

Here is the code I'm trying to work with, however I am receiving an error:

```
 DT::formatStyle(
      columns = cols,
      color = DT::styleInterval(0, c('red', 'green'))

 ) %>%
 DT::formatStyle(
       'metric',
       target = 'row',
       backgroundColor = styleEqual('Total', 'gray'))
```

Comment: You should be able to. You can pipe multiple `formatSignif()` together, so I'd be surprised if you couldn't do the same thing with `formatStyle()`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are even examles in `?formatStyle` as well as [on the github pages documentation](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/functions.html)

```
library(dplyr)
library(DT)

datatable(mtcars) %>%
  formatStyle("am", color = styleEqual(1, "red")) %>%
  formatStyle("cyl", color = styleInterval(7, c("green", "blue")))
```

If you could provide testdata and a complete minimal working example, helping would be easier.

Comment: What if column has Infinity values, Can we make it recognized as Blue color ?